# Remove white top shadow from GCKUIMiniMediaControlsViewController

Tags: swift, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

In swift, with Google Cast SDK, is there an option to **remove white shadow from top** of **GCKUIMiniMediaControlsViewController view**?

```
    let style = GCKUIStyle.sharedInstance()
    
    let miniMediaStyle = style.castViews.mediaControl.miniController

    // ???

    style.apply()
```

I've already check documentation, but I cannot find something about the container shadow.

Eventually, is it possible to act on shadow without using GCKUIStyle?

Answer (score 0):

We are not sure what exactly you asking here, but from what I understood there is no way to remove or change the shadows of our UI.